# sql return distinct rows only

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

I would like to get a unique row for below table

```
Name | Address | Order 
------------------------
ABC  | NYC     | 10    
ABC  | NYC     | 10    
ABC  | NYC     | 11
XYZ  | NYC     | 11
XYZ  | NYC     | 12
PQR  | NYC     | 11
PQR  | NYC     | 11
```

I would like that my result is as below

```
Name | Address | Order 
------------------------
ABC  | NYC     | 10    
ABC  | NYC     | 11
XYZ  | NYC     | 11
XYZ  | NYC     | 12
PQR  | NYC     | 11
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Use the DISTINCT command in your SQL statement

> SELECT DISTINCT Name, Address, Order From MY_SQL_TABLE